# Memory leaks warnings

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a viewcontroller, into this I add a several subviews to his view, add in array(array - its property of parent viewcontroller) and didn't release subviews to add now, but release their in dealloc. I am embarrassed by messages about memory leaks. How can I find any way to solve problem with memory management? Thanks!

```
-(void)someMethod
{
    for(<<something in something>>)
    {
            ValidationColumnViewController *controller = [[ValidationColumnViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(columnsInitialX, 5, validationColumnWidth, validationColumnHeight) andValidationColumn:column withMaxCellsCount:maxCellsCountForValidationColumns];               
            [gameFieldView addSubview:controller.view];
            [validationColumnViewControllers addObject:controller];
    }
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    for(ValidationColumnViewController *controller in validationColumnViewControllers)
    {
        [controller release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely release the objects you create with the line

```
ValidationColumnViewController *controller = [[ValidationColumnViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(columnsInitialX, 5, validationColumnWidth, validationColumnHeight) andValidationColumn:column withMaxCellsCount:maxCellsCountForValidationColumns];
```

Just after you add them to the array (the addObject: call increases the object's retain count by 1), not in the dealloc. If you don't they might be removed from the array before the dealloc by some other call and in that case, you'll leak memory. I think you should also release validationColumnViewControllers in the dealloc method given it is apparently a retained ivar.

Also adding the controller.view object to another view:

```
[gameFieldView addSubview:controller.view];
```

is not a good idea, this increases the controller.view retain count by 1 but not the controller retain count. This means the controller could be deallocated but not its view which will lead to problems (EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when the view tries to talk to its controller).

Also in

```
-(void)dealloc
```

you should always call [super dealloc] at the end of the function, this is what actually causes the object to be deallocated.

Comment: so bad:( What about NSDictionary instead NSArray?

Comment: There is no problem with using an array (adding an object to a dictionary also increases its retain count anyway). Just make sure you release things as many times as they get retained. You can print the retainCount (which is an NSObject property) to check (however this value is meaningless once the object is deallocated so don't use it unless it's meant to be > 0).

Comment: If you think `[gameFieldView addSubview:controller.view];` is a problem, then in ValidationColumnViewController dealloc do `[self.view removeFromSuperview];`. But I think it is probably not a problem. My guess is that gameFieldView will get dealloc'ed when the class the above code is from is dealloc'ed, and the ValidationColumnViewControllers will be retained until then.

Comment: ah!! I just forgot initialize validationColumnViewController property! In this cause, objects not being added to collection and not retained.
I been very confused about it...:))
Stupid situation, very sorry, guys!

Answer (score 4):

Release each one immediately after the addObject call. No need to wait for dealloc.

Comment: I can't. Because it are delegate of some objects(as assign property)

Comment: @user578205 Listen to Graham. You create each instance of ValidationColumnViewController with a retain count of 1. You retain it when you add it to validationColumnViewControllers, resulting in a retain count of 2. You need to release the instance after you add it to the array to bring its retain count back to 1. It's still retained; it's not going anywhere. When your owning object is deallocated, your dealloc method takes care of releasing them at last (though I suggest releasing the array that contains them rather than looping through and releasing them individually).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code will actually work fine, though the recommendations in the other answers are better coding practice and style. You are not getting the advantages of reference counting your way.

The compiler is unable to figure out that your code guarantees the objects in the array will be released. It looks for simple patterns like releasing in the same scope as creating, or retaining instance variables and releasing them in dealloc. If it can't find them, it gives a warning, but that does not necessarily mean you are managing memory wrong, just that the compiler cannot verify that you are doing it right. Doing something outside the patterns the compiler recognizes should rarely be necessary though.